# Can we use Synchronized for each entry instead of ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, synchronized

This is the problem: we want a hash table whose entries are thread-safe.

Suppose I have a hash table of `<String, Long>`, and I want to increase the value of one of the entries thread safely: is the following OK?:

```
HashMap<String , Long> hashTable = new HashMap<String, Long>();
```

Then whenever I want to increase an entry:

```
Synchronized (hashTable.get("key"))
{
    Long value = hashTable.get("key");
    value++;
    hashTable.put("key", value);
}
```

I think it is better than ConcurrentHashMap, as it locks just one entry, unlike ConcurrentHashMap which uses buckets, and lock a group of entries together.

More importantly, I don't know how to increment it using COncurrenHashMap safely. For example I think the following code is not correct:

```
 ConcurrentHashMap<String , Long> hashTable = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>();


 Long value = hashTable.get("key");
 value++;
 hashTable.put("key", value);
```

I think it is not correct, because two threads can read the key one after another, and write one after another and end up in a wrong value.

What do you think guys?

Comment: Have you got any performance figures? Money talks in this context and if you really believe you've got something valuable you should post figures to give people confidence to even look at your algorithm.

Comment: You suggest you have a version of a Map which is more correct or performant than ConcurrentHashMap in a concurrent environment. Beyond inspection, what is your evidence?

Comment: No, I am asking you: is it OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed approach is not thread-safe because the initial `hashTable.get()` operation -- by which you obtain the object on which you intend to synchronize -- is not itself synchronized relative to other threads `put()`ing a value associated with the same key.  Moreover, your code does not account for the possibility of new values being added to the map or keys being removed from the map (so-called "structural modifications").  If ever that can happen, regardless of key, then those actions have to be synchronized with respect to *all* other accesses to the map.

You are right, however, that `ConcurrentHashMap` does not solve these problems either.  It is thread-safe with respect to the individual operations it provides, which include some that `Map` itself does not define, but *series* of operations that must be performed as an uninterrupted unit still need to be protected by synchronization.

I suggest a slightly different approach: use a `ConcurrentHashMap` with `AtomicLong`, which is mutable, as your value type instead of `Long`:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicLong> map;
```

Then, to update the value for a key, even if you're not confident that the key already has an entry in the map, you do this:

```
AtomicLong value = map.putIfAbsent(key, new AtomicLong(0));
long updatedValue = value.incrementAndGet();
```

The `putIfAbsent()` ensures that value objects are not clobbered by conflicting put operations.  The use of `AtomicLong` avoids the need for multiple operations to be jointly synchronized, because only one map access is needed -- the value retrieved is shared by all threads accessing it, and can itself be atomically updated without further accessing the map.

If you can be certain that the map already has a mapping for the given key, then you can simply do this:

```
AtomicLong value = map.get(key);
long updatedValue = value.incrementAndGet();
```

One way or the other, I think this is about the best you can do for the operations you describe and imply.

### Update:

You could even consider combining the two approaches like this:

```
AtomicLong value = map.get(key);

if (value == null) {
    value = map.putIfAbsent(key, new AtomicLong(0));
}

long updatedValue = value.incrementAndGet();
```

That supposes that it will be comparatively rare that there is not already a mapping for the given key, and it avoids creating a new `AtomicLong` in that case.  If no mapping is found then the map must be accessed a second time to ensure that there is a mapping and to get the corresponding value, but here we still need `putIfAbsent()` if we want to avoid synchronization, because it is possible for two threads to both try to add a mapping for the same key, at about the same time.  That's more costly when a new entry needs to be added, but it's possible that it would turn out to be less costly on average than my first suggestion.  As with any performance question, however, it is essential to test.

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf, in the first place, it is essential to understand that unlike `long` primitive values, `Long` objects are immutable.  You cannot, therefore, actually increment a `Long`; if you try, the result is a *different object* with the desired value.  That different object has its own, separate monitor (lock), and threads that hold one's monitor are not thereby synchronized with threads that hold the other's.  That's also why you must, in your version, `put()` the updated value into the map, which otherwise would just continue to hold the old one.

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf, in the second place, you need to recognize that your version synchronizes on the object returned by `hashTable.get()`, but before it can do so, `hashTable.get()` must execute.  In the course of that execution, the thread reads the internal data structure of the map to find the entry for the given key and to extract the associated value; if another thread modifies any of those internal data structures without some form of synchronization between the two threads, then your program is not properly synchronized.

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf, any structural modification of the map can modify parts of the map's internal state that any other operation on the map will read.  Any `put()` with a given key will modify parts of the map's internal state that a `get()` with the same key will read.  Therefore, these operations need to be synchronized with your initial `get()`, but in your proposed code, they are not.  Therefore your code is not properly synchronized, which is to say, not thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. But about the immutibility of Long, I tried this code:

  Long l = new Long(0) ;
  l++;
  System.out.println(l);

It works, fine and print 1. So, doesn't it show that we can increment a Long object?

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf, no, your code does not show that you can increment a `Long`.  The evaluation of `l++` unboxes the `Long` to get a `long`, increments the `long`, autoboxes that value to create a new, *different* `Long` instance, and finally assigns the new `Long` to variable `l`.  The original `Long` retains the same value it had from the beginning, which you can verify if you have another reference to it -- and of course, that also proves that it is a different object.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much :)

Comment: What if instead of Long, I have Array objects as values? Then can I synchronized over them safely? Suppose I used ConcurrentHashMap, instead of HashMap.

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf, If you use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `HashMap`, with one-element arrays as values, then you are close to the solution I in fact recommended.  You can modify my example to work with that, in which case you'll need to synchronize on the `long[]` values before accessing or modifying their contents.  But I don't see any reason to prefer that to what I actually suggested, which should be both clearer and a bit lighter.

Comment: Thanks for your response John. See, I have another HashMap (not this one) whose values are ArrayList and another that has values of SoretedSet. I don't know  what  to do with them? :( I cannot use your soloution for them.