# Locking value objects of a ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

In this post: 
[Can we use Synchronized for each entry instead of ConcurrentHashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470322/can-we-use-synchronized-for-each-entry-instead-of-concurrenthashmap?noredirect=1#comment64344595_38470322)

I asked if we can use Synchronized block to lock only entries of a HashMap, which I learnt we cannot. Now, my question is, if we have a ConcurrentHashMap (not hashMap) with values of type ArrayList, or TreeMap, then can I use that approach (using synchronized). Here what I mean:

```
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();




    synchronized (map.get("key")) {
        //do something with the array thread-safely, 

    }
```

Is it safe? the reason that I am asking is that I don't know how to check this kind of issues by testing.

Comment: _Is it safe?_ is not answerable unless we know what else you might be doing with the values. Is another part of your code using them separately? Are they locking on the corresponding monitor before accessing them?

Comment: You are right. I mean is it thread-safe, if whenever I want to access the arraylist use synchronized block?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use the `putIfAbsent` operation, then it will be thread-safe. You will always be synchronizing (blocking) on the same object reference.

Comment: why I need putIfAbsent?

Comment: Let's say you invoke `map.put("key", new Object());` by many threads at the same time. Each thread can succeed such that you can synchronize on multiple objects. If you instead us `putIfAbsent("key", new Object())` only one thread will succeed and you will sync on that single object.