# How can we have entry-level locking in HashMap?

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

Since, statckoverflow does not allow add more thing to your question in the original question (you can only add comment, not code) I am asking a sequential question to my original question here: 
[Can we use Synchronized for each entry instead of ConcurrentHashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470322/can-we-use-synchronized-for-each-entry-instead-of-concurrenthashmap/38470603?noredirect=1#comment64386235_38470603)

The problem is very simple, and I don't know why for such a simple problem that probably many people have encountered before me I should spend this much time :/

The problem is: I have a hashmap, I want when one thread is working on one of the entries of the hashMap, no any other thread access that object, and I don't want to lock the whole hashMap.

I know that java provides ConcurrentHashMap, but ConcurrentHashMap does not solve the problem, when you want to do thing more complex than simple put and get. Even newly added functions (in Java 8) like merge is not enough for complex scenarios.

For example:

***Suppose I want a hash map that maps strings to ArrayLists. Then for example suppose I want to do this: 
For key k, if there is any entry, add newString to its ArrayList, but if there is no entry for k, create the entry for k such that its ArrayList has newString.***

I was thinking I can do it as follows:

```
                ArrayList<String> tm =new ArrayList<String>();
                tm.add(newString);
                Object result = map.putIfAbsent(k, tm);
                if  (result != null)
                {
                    map.get(k).add(newString);
                }
```

But it does not work, why? suppose putIfAbset return something other than null, then it means that map already has an entry with key k, so I will try to add newString to the ArrayList of the already existing entry, but right before adding, another thread may remove the entry, and then I will get NullPointerException!

So, I found it very difficult to code such things properly.

But I was thinking that if I can simply lock that entry, life will be wonderful!

In my previous post I suggested something very simple that in fact eliminates the need for concurrentHashMap, and provide entry-level locking but some said that is not true because Long is not immutable ... that I didn't get it well.

Now, I implemented and tested it, it looks good to me, but I don't know why other more experienced developers here told me it is not thread-safe :(

This is the exact code that I tested:

MainThread:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class mainThread {

public static HashMap<String, Long> map = new HashMap<String, Long>();

public static void main (String args[])
{
    map.put("k1", new Long(32));


    synchronized(map.get("k1"))
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new threadA());
        t.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

ThreadA:

```
public class ThreadA implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    mainThread.map.put("k2", new Long(21));
    System.out.println(mainThread.map.get("k2"));


    synchronized (mainThread.map.get("k1")) {
        System.out.println("Insdie synchronized of threadA");
    }
}
}
```

It works fine! It prints 21, and after 5 seconds, that mainThread release the lock of map.get("k1"), it prints "Insdie synchronized of threadA"

So, why using this simple approach we cannot provide entry-level locking?! why concurrency should be that much complicated Lol (just kidding)

Comment: Can you store the value in a wrapper object that you lock on when you want to change it, but the key remains the same? That pattern works with ConcurrentMap or a synchronized map.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Can you explain more?

Comment: _"statckoverflow does not allow add more thing to your question "_ -- NOT TRUE. That is what the EDIT button is for.

Comment: Yes, but edit confuses future readers. Some one may answer my question and mention something that I may remove it. Then future reader will confused.

Comment: You miss the point of StackOverflow. If the question is unclear or needs additional information, you should add it. If it invalidates an answer, that answer will be edited or superseded by better answers.

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf - Well obviously.  But the solution to that is to be careful / thoughtful with the way that you edit your Questions.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, there is no standard map implementation that I am aware of that provides entry level locking.

But I think you can avoid the need for that.  For example

**UPDATE ... corrected mistake**

```
ArrayList<String> tm = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> old = map.putIfAbsent(k, tm);
if (old != null) {
    tm = old;
}
synchronized (tm) {
    // can now add / remove entries and this will appear as an atomic
    // actions to other threads that are using `synchronized` to 
    // access or update the list
    tm.add(string1);
    tm.add(string2);
}
```

Yes it is possible that another thread will update the list in the hashmap entry between this thread (possibly) inserting it, and this thread locking it.  However, that doesn't matter.  The (corrected) `putIfAbsent` and the test that follows ensures that everyone will use and lock the same list.

(Assumption: that all threads use this logic when inserting / updating an entry.)

---

Atomically removing the list if it becomes empty is difficult, but I would argue that it is usually unnecessary to do that.

---

**UPDATE 2**

There is a better way:

```
ArrayList<String> tm = map.computeIfAbsent(k, ArrayList::new);
synchronized (tm) {
    ...
}
```

(Thanks Stuart)

---

**UPDATE 3**

> We can do it with merger too.

Maybe, yes.  Something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> tm = new ArrayList<String>;
tm.add(...);
...
map.merge(key, tm, (oldV, newV) -> {oldV.addAll(newV); return oldV});
```

The downside is that you are double-handling all the elements of `tm`; i.e. adding to 2 separate lists (one of which you throw way).

But you could also do this:

```
map.merge(key, tm, (oldV, newV) -> {
      oldV.removeAll(newV); 
      return oldV.size() == 0 ? null : oldV}
);
```

The thing that concerns me is that the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) does not state explicitly that the value `oldV` will be locked while this is happening.  It says:

> "The entire method invocation is performed atomically. Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress ..."

... but it does not explicitly state that there is mutual exclusion on the *value* while this is happening.  (For instance, mixing this approach with `putIfAbsent` / `computeIfAbsent` and an explicit `synchronized` block would most likely be hazardous.  The locking would most likely be on different objects.)

Comment: But tm is in the HashMap, we should first refer to it by calling get method.

Comment: @StephenC Wouldn't that still allow modification of the list between the `putIfAbsent()` call and the `synchronized` block?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: Yes, but it doesn't seem like that'd be a problem.

Comment: `putIfAbsent` returns `null`, not the new value, if there was no previous value for a given key. There should be a null check before assigning the return value over `tm`.

Comment: @JimGarrison: No you couldn't, because you'd be synchronizing on the wrong object.

Comment: @JimGarrison - putIfAbsent certainly returns null if there was no previous value.  and the example code supports that assertion.  the !containsKey branch will return null.

Comment: @JimGarrison: [It seems to return `null` for me.](http://ideone.com/l8VejJ) The null return value lets you distinguish whether there was no old value, or whether the old value happened to be the same object you just tried to insert.

Comment: Yea ... that was a mistake.  Corrected.  Serves me right for not checking the javadoc ... :-(

Comment: The preferred idiom for this is `tm = map.computeIfAbsent(k, ArrayList::new)`. It avoids unnecessary ArrayList creation if the entry is already present. The map has to be a ConcurrentMap in order to guarantee atomicity.

Comment: We can do it with merger too. ArrayList tm; tm.add; tm.add ....; then using merger: map.merge(key, tm, (oldV, newV) -> {oldV.add; oldV.add;... return oldV});

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first huge problem is that you don't even attempt to do any locking for the `put` calls. Those aren't automatically threadsafe for a regular HashMap. You seem to be under the impression that separate HashMap entries are completely independent automatically, but HashMaps don't work that way.

Even if you fix the `put` problem (probably requiring ConcurrentHashMap or a whole-map lock anyway), the parts you actually are locking for aren't locking safely.

Say thread 1 `put`s the entry `"k1": 1`, and thread 2 tries to `get("k1")`. What will thread 2 see?

Well, thread 2 doesn't even try to acquire any locks until the `get` call is *already done*. The `get` call is completely unprotected! Without any happens-before relation between the `put` and the `get`, the `get` call might not see the entry, or it might see the entry, or it might see the map in an inconsistent intermediate state and crash horribly.

Synchronizing on the result of the `get` call is synchronizing far too late.

Comment: So, what is your solution then?

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf: I'd probably do the thing Stephen C posted.

Comment: That one is not the solution to my problem. He is locking on tm, but how can I obtain tm in the first place? That I why I am calling get() fucntion. 

See the text that I made bold

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf: `putIfAbsent` returns `tm`. You don't need a separate `get` call.

Comment: But if in another scenario, I want to only remove something from my hashmap (I don't want to use putIfAbsent), what can I do? And moreover, why putIfAbsent is protected, but get is not?

Comment: Also, putIfAbsent, returns the "previous" value of the key, and null if there was not entry to that key, not the new put entry. According to java doc: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf: For a ConcurrentHashMap, both methods are atomic, but calling one and then the other is not. For a regular HashMap, neither method is atomic. If you want to remove an entry, that's what `remove` is for.

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf: You're right about the `putIfAbsent` return value, though. That needs fixing.

Comment: I want to remove but based on the value of the tm, if tm is empty I want to remove otherwise, I don't want. That's why I need first get tm, lock it, check it, and if tm is emoty, remove the entry from the HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have finally found the solution using merge function. I provide an example, I will edit this post to make it easier for others to read, but I just post now to have your feedback.

Here is the example of a ConcurrentHashMap that has ConcurrentHashMaps as its values (23 and 1 are just two random value for sake of example):

```
    Long intialValue = new Long(3);
    Long addedValue = new Long(10);
    Long removingValue = new Long (5);

    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Long>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    //Initialization....
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Long> i = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Long>();
    i.put(1, intialValue);
    map.put(23, i);
    //......

    //addition
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Long> c = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Long>();
    c.put(1, addedValue);
    map.merge(23, c, (oldHashMap, newHashMap) -> {
        oldHashMap.merge (1, c.get(1), (oldV, newV) -> { 
            if (oldV < newV) return newV; else return oldV; 
            });
        return oldHashMap;
        });



    //removal
    // we want to remove entry 1 from the inner HashMap if its value is less than 2, and if the entry is empty remove the entry from the outer HashMap 
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Long> r = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Long>();
    r.put(1, removingValue);
    map.merge (23, r, (oldHashMap, newHashMap) -> {
    oldHashMap.merge(1, newHashMap.get(1), (oldV, newV) -> {if  (oldV  < newV) return newV; else return oldV;});
    return oldHashMap;
    });
    map.remove(23, r);

    if (map.containsKey(23))
    {
        System.out.println("Map contains key 23");
        if (map.get(23).containsKey(1))
        {
            System.out.println("The value for <23,1> is " + map.get(23).get(1));
        }
    }
```

This is what the code does:

1. **initialization**: first creates the map and puts another map into it for key 23 which has value `initialValue` for key 1.
2. **addition**: Then checks, 1) if for key 23, there is no value, it puts a map that has value addedValue for key 1, otherwise 2) if key 23 has already a value, it checks its value if the value has a value less than `addedValue`, it overwrites it with the `addedValue`, otherwise it leaves it alone.
3. **removal**: Finally, it checks, if for key 23, and for key 1 in the value for 23, the value is less than `removingValue`, it removes that, and if the hashMap of key 23 is empty after this removal, it removes key 23 from the main map.

I tested this code. So for example:

- for 3, 10, 5, the final value for <23,1> is 10.
- for 20, 10, 11, the final value is 20.
- for 3, 10, 11, the final value is nothing,because entry 23 is
  removed.

I hope it is thread-safe as I just used merge method. One disadvantage of this code is that I am adding something to map and then remove it, just because ConcurrentHashMap does not have a method for remove similar to merge. I wish I had this method:

map.remove (keyToRemove, *condition*)